# Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

i am stuck with this issue past 5 days.
i am using vscode on mac device.

Issue i am getting while i run the app from vscode.

if i create apk in terminal that is working fine. no issues are there.

```
flutter doctor
Building flutter tool...
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.2, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H1419 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.60.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

I tried Flutter Clean - no luck.

I reinstalled the flutter - no luck

i removed the flutter extension in vscode and then reinstalled - no luck.

i did the cache repair - no luck

updated the flutter version in pubspec.lock file still not working.

In vscode statusbar i can see flutter version is 2.0.2 but when i run the code it is giving error - flutter version 0.0.0

Now i am out of options what should i try next.

Has anyone faced similar issues?

Comment: Can you share your `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: *"but when i run the code it is giving error - flutter version 0.0.0"* - what code are you running? and what exact error you got?

Comment: A version of 0.0.0 indicates that you have a Flutter SDK installation somewhere (which is a clone of the Git repository) that is missing version tags.  Do you have multiple copies of the Flutter SDK installed?

Comment: @pskink I mean to say when i run the flutter app (Basic App). I am getting the same error as Flutter version is 0.0.0

Comment: @jamesdlin i have single installation of Flutter.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you don't have another installation?  Have you performed a search?

Comment: @jamesdlin yes i did that and also i checked the path variable twice.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

- First Restart your system.
- Open your downloaded Flutter SDK zip folder (folder you get when you download
- flutter sdk from official website) and copy packed-refs and config file which is under <flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable.zip\flutter.git> folder
- Remove these two files form the existing flutter sdk location in your system(which you extracted earlier) and paste these files again.
- Again open android studio and try again by clicking Get dependencies button.
- Click on run application.
- App will run successfully.

Comment: I have tried the above steps. But it is still not working. I am using vscode not the android studio.

Comment: there is something wrong with your Flutter installation.
Please try https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted to fix it.

Comment: I realized that my download of 3.0.5 (latest) didn't have the #packed-refs or #config files. I had to download 3.0.4 and copy these over and it solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to resolve this problem
"Flutter `SDK` version is 0.0.0-unknown"

```
delete Git
```

Answer (score -1):

check Airplane mode

if Airplane mode on

switch off,
then restart vs code or android studio

and complete your work!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).